# JavaScript canvas: Ball leaving a trail behind it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Developing a simple canvas application where you can shoot bullets with a gun, but the bullet leaves a trail behind it. I've tried clearing the canvas with clearRect and by setting the canvas's width to itself, but no luck. Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/ayo1qfab/1). Relevant snippets:

Bullet.prototype:

```
Bullet.prototype = {
    render: function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.arc(this.coordinates.x, this.coordinates.y, this.size.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        return this;
    },
    animate: function () {
        this.coordinates.x += this.velocity.speed.x;
        return this;
    }
};
```

update():

```
function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gun.render();
    gun.shoot();
    bullets.forEach(function(bullet) {
        bullet.render().animate();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

How do I prevent the ball from leaving a trail?

Comment: Something in this code is hogging the CPU really bad. Crashing my browser tab eventually.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it's quite slow. Not sure why. EDIT: Figured it out. gun.shoot() was called every frame, and it should only be called once, so I moved it to main().  Updated the jsFiddle link as well. Unfortunately, it still leaves a trail behind.

Comment: You can put a debugger in the code and open the chrome console to inspect what's happening. Each call the update seems to be worse than the last, from what I can tell on the chrome profiler. Each frame renders slower than the previous

Comment: Ah, everytime you call update you're shooting a new bullet. That's why each frame is slower to update than the previous.

Comment: Got it updated a bit so that it's not crashing. Updated it to only render 1 bullet. Once the trail is fixed, you can work on adding more. https://fiddle.jshell.net/82y2vk6b/7/ (you probably won't want it to shoot a bullet every time it calls update, but that's the next thing to work on after fixing the trail)

Comment: Can't access the fiddle, but you have to create a new Path2D at each `bullet.render`: `render: function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(t...`

Comment: Ah, using beginPath() and closePath(). Works like a charm. Thanks. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'd also look into libraries that make working with canvas easier. (Paper.js, Two.js, Fabric.js) Or if you want to look into libraries specifically for making HTML5 games, there are plenty of those.

Comment: Yeah, I use Phaser.js, but I'm trying to learn how it all works under the hood, so just using vanilla JS ATM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each `Bullet.draw()` you are adding more `arc`shape to the same Path2d.
`ctx.fill()` will then apply to this whole Path2d, including the "trail".

What you need is to create a new Path2d at each Bullet.

```
Bullet.prototype = {
    render: function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath(); // this is a new Path2d
        ctx.arc(this.coordinates.x, this.coordinates.y, this.size.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        return this;
    },
    animate: function () {
        this.coordinates.x += this.velocity.speed.x;
        return this;
    }
};
```

Note that since `arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,0)` is indeed a closed arc (a circle), you don't need to call `ctx.closePath()`.